# How to Read a WebPage with Python and write to a flat file?

Tags: python

**Very novice at Python here**. 
Trying to read the table presented at this page (w/ the current filters set as is) and then write it to a csv file.

http://www65.myfantasyleague.com/2017/options?L=47579&O=243&TEAM=DAL&POS=RB

I tried this next approach. It creates the csv file but does not fill it w/ the actual table contents.

Appreciate any help in advance. thanks.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www65.myfantasyleague.com/2017/optionsL=47579&O=243&TEAM=DAL&POS=RB'
csv_file='DAL.RB.csv'
pd.read_html(requests.get(url).content)[-1].to_csv(csv_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, try to emphasize your problems better, try to debug and don't put everything in one line. With that said, your specific problem here was the index and the missing `?` in the code (after `options`):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www65.myfantasyleague.com/2017/options?L=47579&O=243&TEAM=DAL&POS=RB'
#                                                  -^-
csv_file='DAL.RB.csv'

pd.read_html(requests.get(url).content)[1].to_csv(csv_file)
#                                      -^-
```

This yields a `CSV` file with the table in it.

Comment: Though, my problem now is to find out how to avoid deleting the existing file. Cause otherwise, I am getting an IOError Permission denied (if I don't delete the file).

Comment: Sorry ... this is truly first time post at stackflow. Getting used to the mechanism here. I now did accept your solution